# Django - Getting AttributeError 'User' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data' while cleaning form data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I was trying to make a user registration page in Django.
everything went fine. but when I submit the form data I get this below error

> AttributeError 'User' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

[Image of that AttributeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIKnJ.png)

I searched on stackoverflow and found that the object.cleanded_data should be placed after object.is_valid() else one should face the AttributeError.
But I placed that after checking is_valid() still getting error.
my codes:

views.py

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = "music/registration_form.html"

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            username = user.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = user.cleaned_data["password"]
            user.set_password(password)
            user.username = username
            user.save()

            user = authenticate(username= username, password= password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return  redirect("music:index")

        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password"]
```

I cant find where I made mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `form.save()` is an instance of the model, not the form. You should be accessing `form.cleaned_data`.

However there is no need to get the username here as the form will already have set it.

```
user = form.save(commit=False)
password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```